# Detecting onclicks with javascript

Tags: javascript, image, loops, input

Does anyone know of a way of detecting which one out of a series of image input buttons has been clicked on, and execute some javascript accordingly?

for example if an 'about' button is clicked, the 'about' header on the page would turn blue.
I can do this individually but is there a loop or something to slim it down? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what have you tried? why didn't it work? you may want to look into [event delegation](http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/events).

Comment: You want to leave elements "hover" in the menu according to the visited page? Is it?

Comment: When I do this in YUI, I use delegate, where you delegate from a parent element, and one handler receives all the click events for matching children. Then in the one method, you just check the IDs (or other properties) of the buttons/etc to the check which action to take.

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: I've tried doing it with seperate function like this...  http://jsfiddle.net/AdamMartin121/j4Bes/   and i'm just wanting to use JavaScript, no JQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your buttons share a class you can use `document.querySelectorAll` to select all buttons and `Array.prototype.forEach.call` for the iteration:

```
<button class="about-button" id="a">a</button>
<button class="about-button" id="b">b</button>
<button class="about-button" id="c">c</button>
<script>
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.about-button'), function(el) {
        el.addEventListener('click', imageButtonClickHandler);
    });

    function imageButtonClickHandler() {
        alert('button clicked: ' + this.id);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thankyou! how would I then make the corresponding titles change depending on which one is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you can use the `.on` method:

```
$("#about").on("click", function(event){
  $(this).css("background-color", "blue"); // Or RGB color, just like in the CSS
});
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/on/ and http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

The question is not fully clear, but I'll try to answer it based on some assumptions.

If you are creating the image buttons dynamically, then I would attach one onclick event handler to all the images buttons being added, and pass 'this' as the parameter to the handler. That way the click handler can look at the DOM element passed in.

```
<a onclick="imageClicked(this)"><img src="about.jpg" /></a>
```

If the elements are declared on the page, and not added dynamically, I would bind the click event for each image button if they are not that many (as @Joshua Brodie has pointed out). If there are a lot of them, I would have one click handler and have data specific to the image button in a "data" attribute.

```
<a class="imgbtn" data-buttonname="about"><img src="about.jpg" /></a>

$('.imagebtn').bind('click', function () {
  console.log($(this).data('buttonname')); // about
});
```